# iptables doesn't redirect http traffic to my Squid proxy!

Tags: proxy, iptables, squid, transparent-proxy

I arranged a transparent Squid proxy which listens to port 3128 on localhost, to block some web sites.

I've tested the proxy using Firefox, and it works.

Then I ran this, hoping to redirect all the http requests to the proxy:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Sadly, nothing happens. The other browsers in my system don't seem to be using the proxy. I don't want to configure each browser, to use the proxy either.

`sudo iptables -L` shows no rules assigned.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, and using a 3G USB modem (`ppp0`) to connect to the Internet. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are missing the destination port, try following

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Without **dport**, you are forwarding traffic with destination port 3128 to local port 3128. What you want is traffic with destination port 80 forward to local port 3128.

Additionally, to show **nat** rules, use

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

However, the above rules will not work for a transparent proxy setup on the same machine of the browser, because *PREROUTING* chain alters packges before routing from a remote client and it will not do anything for locally generated packets. Thus we should use *OUTPUT* chain for packets locally generated which are going out from the system.

Try following instead

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner proxy --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

It will only redirect traffic for processes other than the ones owned by `proxy` user.

Without `-m owner ! --uid-owner proxy`, it will not work because the rules will also caught the proxy server outgoing traffic and end up in a loop.

Comment: :( No effect.. This is the output: http://i.imgur.com/OXtNVEw.jpg

Comment: what is output of 'iptables -t nat -L'

Comment: Now I'm seeing a new NAT rule : http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/9aAd1e.jpg

Comment: ..but the other browsers aren't going through the proxy. My squid access.log doesn't record network activities of other browsers.

Comment: How is your proxy setup? Is it on the same box running the browser or a separate machine? also post output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: I'm running the proxy on the same machine I run Web Browsers. It's a transparent Proxy. The proxy runs on the localhost:1328. Here is my squid.conf file:
http://pastebin.com/R2RRhnbP

Comment: Here is the **ifconfig** output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5710110/

Comment: I'm using **ppp0** device

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Ok.... The last command of the your answer returns this : ip_tables: **Invalid Argument. owner match: used from hooks PREROUTING, but only valid from OUTPUT/POSTROUTING**

Comment: Hey John!! It works when a small modification is done to your command! 
**sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner proxy --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128**
Couldn't have done without your loop theory
**Thanks a lot!**
(your bounty will be added after 19 hours, as promised :)

Comment: You are welcome. I found out I made another mistake in my original answer too. I am too used to 8080 for proxy. LOL.

Comment: @JohnSiu I signed up on askubuntu just to up vote your answer! Thanks!